# How to compile with FLTK under Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, fltk

I am using Code:blocks under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I am attempting to compile my first program using FLTK and I get the following errors.

```
Linking console executable: bin/Debug/<project name removed for security reasons>
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
4 errors, 0 warnings
```

Is there something else I need to install, or a path I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

To build an FLTK project in Code::Blocks 16.01 on UBUNTU 16.04.

Install FLTK and two additional packages:

```
$ sudo apt install fltk1.3-dev
$ sudo apt install libxft-dev
$ sudo apt install libxinerama-dev
```

After this, you can define an FLTK project, and build it without problems.

If you do not install the libxft-dev and libXinerama-dev packages, you will indeed get these error messages listed in question about missing libraries (-lXft, -lfontconfig, -lXinerama).

The reason these packages are not installed automatically with fltk1.3-dev is because they're only 'suggested', and not a hard dependency. This can be seen here:

[package: libfltk1.3-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libfltk1.3-dev)

However, the 'fltk-config' flag which is used by Code:Blocks to decide what libraries to link in requires them.

For more detail on the fltk-config flag, see:

[Beginners Guide to fltk-config](http://www.fltk.org/articles.php?L599)

For completeness, here the links to the 2 additional packages:

[package: libxft-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libxft-dev)

[package: libxinerama-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libxinerama-dev)

Answer (score 0):

The dev version of libraries used by FLTK might be missing  http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libfltk1.3 .

You can use `apt-get` to install them : libxft-dev,  libfontconfig1-dev and libxinerama-dev.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously do not have libXft, libfontconfig and libXinerama installed on your machine. If you installed FLTK using Ubuntu package manager, then you should report missing dependency information in the FLTK package.

Typically we do this by finding out who is the package maintainer, and send e-mail to that person.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get code:blocks 13.12 working with FTLK on Raspberry Pi using Raspian.  CodeBlocks gave me those same errors "cannot find -lXft" "cannot find -lfontconfig" and "cannot find -lXinerama".

I used the add/remove software provided with Raspian and searched for each of the following libraries libxft-dev, libfontconfig1-dev and libxinerama-dev and then I installed them using the package manager. When I restarted codeblocks FLTK worked fine!